# Network profiles in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

Is there a way to simulate slow network in Firefox? There're network profiles in Chromium, I want something similar in Firefox.
[image]

Comment: As a workaround, you may throttle network interface https://superuser.com/questions/66574/how-to-throttle-bandwidth-on-a-linux-network-interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open responsive design mode to get it appear.

- Open mobile mode [image]
- Select throttle profile [image]

You also can use [throttle-proxy server](https://github.com/mistakster/throttle-proxy):

- `npm install -g throttle-proxy`
- `throttle-proxy`
- From firefox: Settings -> Preferences -> General -> Network Proxy, Settings -> Automatic proxy configuration url `http://localhost:3128/`